# Floor to Ceiling wall mirror - Wallpaper?

Tags: walls, mirror, wallpaper

What can we do to this bathroom wall with floor to ceiling mirror?   Looking to do a quick makeover - not wanting to pull the mirror off and patch the drywall.    We are considering peel-and-stick wallpaper over the mirror as a quick fix.  What kind of prep would be needed? I assume cleaning, light sanding with 400, then a primer?   What kind of primer?
[image]

Comment: I cannot *imagine* why someone would want to remove this.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new here - can't tell if you are serious or if that is sarcasm?  ;)   Want to remove it because it's like being in a hall of mirrors!

Comment: Pretty sure that was sarcasm.

Comment: I'm guessing sarcasm.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, sarcasm sometimes doesn't come across in a facetious remark.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the "fake stained glass" window products that are commonly available if doing anything to this. "Privacy film", etc...

You clean the glass and they are applied with a mist of water and a squeegee to remove bubbles. They stay put (I've had them in a bathroom for several years on windows, as better than having curtains/blinds) and when you decide to remove them they can be peeled right off - since it's some sort of static cling rather than an actual adhesive, there's no fuss and no mess to clean up.

Comment: The films are fairly inexpensive and I have used them a few times mostly to reduce the brightness and made sure the realtor mentioned the film could be removed. I would suggest watching a online video on how to clean the mirror and apply the film, we used single edged razor blades and window cleaner to remove any surface bumps as these will affect the look of the film.  The second important thing is lint free cloths to wipe with then spray apply film and squeegee any bubbles and trim to size.  With that said this is decorating question and off topic but the film is my preferred method also.